# All my css files don't seem to be active when uploading the landing page using cpanel

Tags: html, css, sass, cpanel

Here is the page I'm talking about https://abanoubnabil.com/landing/
It seems perfect when I see it on local host, but when uploading it, neither the css files nor the images are loading.
Can someone help?

Comment: Please learn how to use the browser's developer tools, learn how to "debug" web pages. Read https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The css isn't loading because the file path is incorrect.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style/style.css" media="">
```

**404**
https://abanoubnabil.com/public/css/style/style.css

The correct path is:

https://abanoubnabil.com/landing/public/css/style/style.css

You need to edit the paths in your code to include the **/landing/** directory.